# Вывод любых структур на экран

Tags: c#, c++, структуры-данных

Как можно сделать универсальный код, что бы он выводил все поля любых структур. Пример:

```
//пример одной структуры, и как должна отрабатывать
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    int a;
    float b;
} structEx;
#pragma pack(pop)

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    structEx x;
    x.a = 4;
    x.b = 4.2;
    cout << x.a << ";" << x.b << endl; // эту строчку хочу универсальной сделать!

    return 0;
}
```

вот пример второй программы

```
//пример второй структуры, и как должна отрабатывать
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    char c;
    float bb;
    double d[4];
} structEx;
#pragma pack(pop)

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    structEx x;
    x.c = 21;
    x.bb = 14.2;
    x.d[0] = 1.2;
    x.d[1] = 2.62;
    x.d[2] = 3.24;
    x.d[3] = 4.32;
    cout << x.c << ";" << x.bb << ";"
           << x.d[0] << ";" << x.d[1] << ";" << x.d[2] << ";"
            << x.d[3] << endl; // эту строчку хочу универсальной сделать!

    return 0;
}
```

---

Понятно, без больших мучений - никак.
А как можно хотя бы немного упростить/автоматизировать? Или использовать может язык c#? синтаксис там предельно близок.

Comment: Ну нет в С++ рефлексии...

Comment: @Harry, ну извратиться можно :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453

Comment: состояние объекта - всего лишь кусок памяти в рантайм. Как, например, интерпретировать union?

Comment: @PinkTux "О, месье понимает толк в извращениях!..." (с) Анекдот

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать отладочную информацию. т.е. процесс в рантайм парсит отладочную информацию для самого себя и на основании ее печатает содержимое структур. По факту это аналог рантайм рефлексии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# это можно написать метод, вроде:

```
void PrintFields<T>(T obj)
{
    foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{field.Name} = {field.GetValue(obj)}");
    }
}
```

который будет выводить значения всех публичных экземплярных полей структуры или класса. Вот небольшой пример:

```
class Test
{
    public int x;

    public int y;
}

var t = new Test
{
    x = 1,
    y = 2,
};

// здесь выведется
// x = 1
// y = 2
Print(t);
```

Сомневаюсь, что удобство вывода структур может являться основанием для выбора языка программирования.

UPD

Написал небольшой пример:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = new T1
        {
            a = 4,
            b = 4.2f
        };

        var t2 = new T2
        {
            c = (char)21,
            bb = 14.2f,
            d = new[] { 1.2, 2.62, 3.24, 4.32 }
        };

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt", false))
        {
            PrintFields(sw, t1);
            sw.WriteLine("***");
            PrintFields(sw, t2);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void PrintFields<T>(StreamWriter sw, T obj)
    {
        foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            sw.Write(ConvertFieldToString(field, obj));
        }

        sw.WriteLine();
    }

    static string ConvertFieldToString<T>(FieldInfo fieldInfo, T obj)
    {
        var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);

        if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsArray)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var array = (Array)value;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append($"{array.GetValue(i)};");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        return $"{value.ToString()};";
    }
}

class T1
{
    public int a;

    public float b;
}

class T2
{
    public char c;

    public float bb;

    public double[] d;
}
```

Вот, что выводит программа:

> 4;4,2;
>
> ---
>
> ;14,2;1,2;2,62;3,24;4,32;

Вроде, отвечает запросам в исходном примере.

Comment: мне нужно написать программу для парсинга разных структур... языки многие я знаю. Программа которая создает файл для парсинга написана на с++. И у меня есть как объявлена структура. И вот думаю как легче всего это сделать

Comment: @KtoTo, я не понял, причем тут вывод любых структур? Что должна ваша программа делать?

Comment: мне нужно их "вывести" в файл... В идеале: на вход передается структура и файл парсинга,  на выходе записать в таблицу все значения всех полей.

Comment: @KtoTo, структура в каком виде передается? Это файл, это скомпилированный код на C? Что содержит файл парсинга? Что за таблица?

Comment: "0500 0000 cccc 8c40 0800 0000 3233 9340
0b00 0000 9899 9940 0e00 0000 feff 9f40
1100 0000 6466 a640 1400 0000 cacc ac40" на вход, и я знаю  что структура такая: typedef struct {
 int a;
 float b;
} structEx; -- тогда я должен вывести в файл: 5; 4.4\n
8; 4.6 \n
11; 4.8\n
14; 5\n
17; 5.2\n
20; 5.4\n
23; 5.6\n
26; 5.8\n
29; 6\n
32; 6.2\n

Comment: @KtoTo, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 7):

Думаю, что самым простым для Вас будет определить операторы вывода для структур:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    float b;
} structEx;

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &ss, const structEx &x)
{
    ss
            << x.a
            << ";"
            << x.b;
    return ss;
}

typedef struct {
    char c;
    float bb;
    double d[4];
} structEx2;

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &ss, const structEx2 &x)
{
    ss
            << x.c
            << ";"
            << x.bb
            << x.d[0]
            << x.d[1]
            << x.d[2]
            << x.d[3];
    return ss;
}


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    {
        structEx x;
        x.a = 4;
        x.b = 4.2;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }

    {
        structEx2 x;
        x.c = 21;
        x.bb = 14.2;
        x.d[0] = 1.2;
        x.d[1] = 2.62;
        x.d[2] = 3.24;
        x.d[3] = 4.32;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```